# Some general keymap doesn't work anymore (Intellij)

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

It's a very strange bug I have now .. For unidentified reason some keymaps doesn't work anymore. The two keymaps I have problems with for now are the one that give (€) and the one that give (}). My keyboard is Azerty and I have no problem elsewhere on my computer.

As you can see I cannot close the bracket or write (€) which is annoying .. I didn't touch anything and even a reinstallation of Intellij doesn't change this.

Also these keymaps are working on settings or console (inside Intellij) and maybe other part but not in the editor of course.

I hope someone heard about this strange behavior :/

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Which keyboard locale are you using?

Comment: With Windows ? Azerty (french)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, I also have a french AZERTY keyboard. It's a problem of shortcut conflicts.

In Intellij 15.0.3 :

File / Settings / Keymap

At the right of the dialog you have a little "magnify icon" with the hint "Find Actions by short cut", click on it

A little dialog box will appear, just type the shortcut (for the close bracket AltGr+"}"). Intellij will show you the command, just right click on select "Remove Ctrl+Alt+Equal".

Same thing for the euro sign.

Here is a screen shot :
[image]

As we say in french "Un dessin vaut mieux qu'un long discours"

Comment: The problem and the solution is the same for WebStorm

Comment: Well thanks a lot, it works with latest ultimate version.